# Changing value of a PHP string based on a condition check with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Basically, on my HTML display page, `mainHTML.php` I include a PHP file called `phpFunctions.php` with some of the PHP functions I made and call these functions. One of them in particular gets information from a SQL database and makes a table from it.

On `mainHTML.php`, I have an ajax script that gets the value from a select box that is on same page, on change.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="selectBox"]').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajaxScript.php', //if bug change to ajaxScript.php
                data: {valueChange: value },
                dataType: 'html'
        }).done(function(response){
           $('.response-holder').html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My ajaxScript looks like so. At the moment, all I can get it to do is echo something based on the value of the select box.

```
<?php
$status = $_POST['valueChange'];

if($status == 'height'){
    echo "ORDER BY height";
}

if($status == 'weight'){
    echo "ORDER BY weight";
}
?>
```

All of this works fine but then I come into a problem. I don't know how I can append the SQL string present in a function in `phpFunctions.php` so that it may be modified based on the `ajaxScript.php` condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put it in a session variable.

Comment: You want to add "ORDER BY weight" this to sql query string and execute that query?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The query is already being executed without any ORDER BY at first. I'm trying to make it so that choosing an option will sort the table