# Setting a session variable to the value of an Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

Following this thread [Changing value of a PHP string based on a condition check with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015977/changing-value-of-a-php-string-based-on-a-condition-check-with-ajax), I have tried setting to a session variable the value of select box that is acquired using Ajax.

I started the session on mainHTML.php. My `ajaxScript.php` looks like this. sortValue is the session value I am trying to write to and valueChange is the value of the select box.

```
    <?php
    $_SESSION["sortValue"] = $_POST['valueChange']; //this doesn't show the select value dynamically
    echo $_SESSION["sortValue"]; this does
    ?>
```

At the end of mainHTML.php, after having called all my PHP functions, I try calling `echo $_SESSION["sortValue"];`, but this value doesn't seem to change dynamically when selecting different options.

It is stuck to a single value. I may need to do something with the session (destroy or unset) but I am not sure. How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the session before you can run:

```
$_SESSION["sortValue"] = $_POST['valueChange'];
```

So, use ..

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["sortValue"] = $_POST['valueChange'];
```

Comment: By putting this in the ajaxScript, the session isn't starting in the correct time, so I get an error (undefined var) when calling the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

did you start your session?

```
bool session_start ( void )
```

see api:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php

Comment: Yes, I mention it in the post

Comment: When writing it again, it says `A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

Comment: add  echo $_POST['valueChange']; does the variable exists?

Comment: Yes, and it is changing dynamically when clicking on different options. The sessions start however isnt

Comment: Ok. try to unset the session variable before you add it. unset($_SESSION['sortValue']);

Comment: Should I be putting that at the top of my ajaxScript file?